How do you draw graphics in C/C++ without external libraries?
I’m trying to find out how to draw graphics in C/C++ without any external libraries. I know it is possible because I’m pretty sure the libraries are programmed in either C or C++ and I want to know how. Do they use their own virtual machine sort of like I’m pretty sure Java works, or do they access your machines video memory? I’m mainly asking about libraries like OpenGL and SDL2.
I’ve tried the win32 api but realized that it’s technically an external library and also even if it isn’t, are there any other ways? I’m also avoiding win32 cuz of how complicated it looks but I might just be being a wussy.

C++ does not have graphics as part of the Standard C++ Library.  You'll have to use an external library.  C does not have graphics as part of the Standard C Library.  You'll have to use an external library.  C is not C++; C++ is not C.  There is no language called C/C++ (although I'm working on a language that I'm calling C/C++ based on OCaml).

how would you do that ? send zeros and ones to the monitor ?! the OS controls the monitor and your GPU and gives you the ability to manipulate them using those APIs, so  you need some API to draw on screen.

You cannot put OpenGL and SDL next to each other. OpenGL libraries are provided by your graphics card manufacturer and they translate the very high level OpenGL drawing commands to low-level drawing operations for the graphics card to consume. SDL in turn provides drawing commands that translate to OpenGL drawing commands.

@AhmedAEK "send zeros and ones to the monitor ?!" - well, this is pretty much what we do with bare-metal or could do and done back in the DOS times. Not that far-fetched. Sure, not something we do with modern OS.

Your best bet is a cross-platform library such as SDL, SFML, Raylib.

C++ is specified to run on hardware that's basically just a chip with a couple of pins you can wiggle to get the data out. No graphics. No network. No keyboard and mouse. No boats, no planes, no motor cars. Not a single luxury. So it's careful about what it requires of a C++ implementation. On the plus side, a system that simple will generally allow direct access to the hardware, but on the downside... No hardware.

This is similar to the folks who, over the years, took on porting the Borland Graphics Interface (BGI, the infamous "graphics.h") to non-DOS systems. The most useful re-implementations of the  once-simple library maintain the external appearance of simplicity by sitting on top of complicated libraries like SDL that can navigate modern systems to get the drawing done.

No modern OS that I know of allows direct access to video memory. It is all mediated through the driver for the graphics card or chip. That is in turn mediated by the OS. There is very little to be learned from trying to bypass these two layers.
If you just want to plot pixels and nothing else, other people have had success with raylib.

Is raylib programmed in c or c++? If so, how did the developers make it work?

Read the source code or at least the site. OpenGL


I’m trying to find out how to draw graphics in C/C++ without any external libraries.

C does not define graphics functions.
